# Django Form with If function produce same result for every if combination

Tags: django, if-statement, django-views, django-forms

I'm still learning Django, and in this project of mine I try to create very simple quizz-like program that will recommend programming language based on user interest.

So,

1. There are 3 question, user only need to answer yes/no
2. After the form is submitted, it'll be processed using if and recommendation will be produced according to user answer

example:

1. if user answer yes, yes, yes, my program will recommend "Javascript, HTML/CSS, React JS, Angular,Figma".
2. if user answer yes, yes, no, my program will recommend "HTML/CSS, Javascript, Flutter"

And the problem is, no matter what combination I use, my program will always return "Javascript, HTML/CSS, React JS, Angular, Figma"(first response in my if)

Here is the detail of my code

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"
    
class Answer(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    webdev = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    mobdev = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    uiux = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name.name}, {self.webdev}, {self.mobdev}, {self.uiux}"

class Result(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    response = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Unidentified')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name.name} {self.response}"
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class Quizzes(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = [
        (True, 'Tertarik'),
        (False, 'Tidak Tertarik')
    ]
    name = forms.CharField(label='Siapakah nama anda?', max_length=20)
    wd = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget = forms.RadioSelect,
        choices = CHOICES,
        label = "Apakah anda tertarik dengan Web Development?"
    )
    md = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget = forms.RadioSelect,
        choices = CHOICES,
        label = "Apakah anda tertarik dengan Mobile Development?"
    )
    ix = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget = forms.RadioSelect,
        choices = CHOICES,
        label = "Apakah anda tertarik dengan UI / UX?"
    )
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from . forms import *
from . models import *
# Create your views here.

def home(response):
    if response.method == 'POST':
        form = Quizzes(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            wd = form.cleaned_data['wd']
            md = form.cleaned_data['md']
            ix = form.cleaned_data['ix']

            q = User.objects.create(name=name)
            q.save()
            q.answer_set.create(webdev=wd, mobdev=md, uiux=ix)

            if wd and md and ix:
                q.result_set.create(response='Javascript, HTML/CSS, React JS, Angular, Figma')
            elif wd and not md and not ix:
                q.result_set.create(response='Javascript, HTML/CSS, PHP')
            elif not wd and md and not ix:
                q.result_set.create(response='Java, Kotlin, Flutter, Swift')
            elif not wd and not md and ix:
                q.result_set.create(response='Canva, Figma, Adobe')
            elif not wd and md and ix:
                q.result_set.create(response='Swift, Kotlin, Flutter, Java')
            elif wd and not md and ix:
                q.result_set.create(response='HTML/CSS, Javascript, Canva, React, Figma')
            elif wd and md and not ix:
                q.result_set.create(response='HTML/CSS, Javascript, Flutter')
            else:
                q.result_set.create(response='None of our recommendations match your interest')

        return HttpResponseRedirect(f"/{q.id}")
    else:
        form = Quizzes()
    return render(response, 'home.html', {'form' : form})

def result(response, id):
    u = User.objects.get(id=id)
    a = u.answer_set.all()
    r = u.result_set.all()
    
    return render(response, 'result.html', {'u' : u, 'r' : r, 'a' : a})
```

result.html for showing the recommendation

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block result %}
    {{ u.name }}
    <br>
    {{ a }}
    <br>
    {{ u.result_set.all }}

{% endblock %}
```

I have try changing the default value of my booleanfield in models.py to True and False (without quotes) and the problem still persist.
And sorry if there is confusion in my question, as I am not native in english language, thank you.

Edit :

I tried to print out the datatype from my database, and it always return `False` and I don't know why.
When I check the value of class `Answer` using `Answer.objects.all()` there is `True` value inside it. But when I print the datatype through my html by using this views.py

```
    a = u.answer_set.first()
    wt = type(a.webdev)
    mt = type(a.mobdev)
    uiux = type(a.uiux)
```

and this result.html

```
    <p>data type for each answer : </p>
    {{ wt }}, {{ mt }}, {{ uiux }}
```

It always return False, no matter which question it is. But if it always return `False` then why did the code produce `Javascript, HTML/CSS, React JS, Angular, Figma` and not `None of our recommendations match your interest`?

Comment: did you debug which data is passed from the cleaned_data? i think it will be "True" and "False" as strings - that could be the issue - because it always evaluates to True in this case (only empty strings evaluate to False)

Comment: I have. in my result.html I code `{{ a }}` for printing out user answer, and I think it works correctly because in the page it stated the boolean combination that I input. But the result still doesn't changes, regardless of the combination.

Comment: please print in your views.py `print(wd)` and `print(type(wd))` that should be `<class 'bool'>` and not `<class 'str'>`

Comment: I try to display it's type through my html, but the result is not what I exptected. 
the html return all false, which really confuse me

Comment: please print it in the views.py - you see it in the console

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still not familiar with terminal or console so I print it out through my html. You can check my edited post to see my code and the produced result in html.
Still, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found my error, in my views.py I use `wd`, `md`, and `ix` from the user response for `if` function, but the if doesn't work, same result for every combination.

Then I change them to `qw`, `qm`, and `qx` taken directly from the database

```
qw = q.answer_set.first().webdev
qm = q.answer_set.first().mobdev
qx = q.answer_set.first().uiux
```

And now the `if` is working.
And as for printing the type, I have figure out how to print it through the terminal and it indeed produced `<class 'bool'>`, but I still don't know why it return `False` if used in views.py and html
But still, my issue is now resolved. Thank you
It seems because of that the `if` function doesn't work(I still don't know why), so